# Pandas - Data Series - TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

C is a Data series with shape of (10000000, ) with dtypes of dtype(< M8[ns]).  I want to create a dataseries which only contain one hour of C.

```
 c.between_time('22:00:00','23:00:00')
```

This is the error that I get

```
 TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: you probably need to add the index to the series of type "DateTimeIndex" (and of course it becomes a dataframe), the index currently must be integers

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: convert it to a dataframe

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a dataframe by initializing an empty dataframe.
I created a sample of 3 dummy times in Series

```
import pandas as pd  
C = pd.Series(['22:00:00','22:30:00','23:00:00'])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['C'] = C

#set index to the obervations after converting them to type datetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(C)
print df

print df.between_time(df['C'][0],df['C'][2])
```

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I have a quick question: some of my entries are in the form of 2015-10-05 02:21:36 and some in the form of 2015-10-05. Do you know how can I remove the second ones?

Comment: The output of this gives me NAN: df = df.ix[df.time.str.len() > 14]

Comment: What are the contents of the column called 'time' ?

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question for it as it is out of scope of the original question.