# Remove Bad data from Data Series without hour

Tags: python, pandas

C is a Data series with shape of (10000000, ) with dtypes of dtype(< M8[ns]).

```
C.head()
```

shows data in the form of 2015-10-05 02:21:36, however I have some entries in the form of 2010-01-01. How can I remove those without hours?  I figure out that in this "2010-01-01" type: hour, minutes and seconds are all zero so:

I tried this

```
c[(c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.hour) != 0) & (c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.minute) != 0) & (c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.second) != 0)]
```

But I might have some entries with this entries 2015-10-05 00:00:00. This way I eliminate them. What is the best and correct way to do it?

Comment: Off the top of my head, extract the format of the date, check against the format you want to keep, and drop all records from the dataframe or series that doesn't match your desired format.

Comment: those observations are present as they are in a string format. Convert the entire column observations to the datetimeIndex type and you will automatically have the missing hours:mins:seconds as 00:00:00

Comment: I did exacly the same thing and then remove those 00:00:00 from the data series by the above command.

Comment: Do you want to remove the 00:00:00 rows out of the DataFrame or not? If you do, try the [`dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor).

Answer (score 1):

Answering both of your questions together here. This one and [Pandas - Data Series - TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453164/pandas-data-series-typeerror-index-must-be-datetimeindex).

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        from datetime import time

In [2]: c = pd.Series(['2015-10-20 19:56:23', '2015-10-08', '2015-10-15 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 17:00:00'])
        c
Out[2]: 0    2015-10-20 19:56:23
        1             2015-10-08
        2    2015-10-15 00:00:00
        3    2015-10-02 17:00:00
        dtype: object

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(list(c), columns=['time'])
        df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
        df
Out[3]:     time
        0   2015-10-20 19:56:23
        1   2015-10-08 00:00:00
        2   2015-10-15 00:00:00
        3   2015-10-02 17:00:00

In [4]: clean_df = df[df['time'].dt.time != time(0,0,0)]
        clean_df
Out[4]:     time
        0   2015-10-20 19:56:23
        3   2015-10-02 17:00:00

In [5]: clean_df[(time(19,0,0) <= clean_df['time'].dt.time) &
                 (clean_df['time'].dt.time < time(20,0,0))]
Out[5]:     time
        0   2015-10-20 19:56:23
```

Does this solve both of your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Change to "&" to "|".  When you have "&", you remove this 08:50:00, which is not a BAD(00:00:00) time.

```
c[(c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.hour) != 0) | (c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.minute) != 0) | (c['time'].apply(lambda x:x.second) != 0)]
```

Comment: You are removing all data this way! Try it out.