# How to filter data in Pandas between times?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter stock price data in between certain times of the day using Pandas. I have tried a few different ways but all producing errors. This is my code... The error is Index must be date time which I thought it was already. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


df = pd.read_csv("IBMstockprices.csv")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
df.between_time('08:00', '12:00')
```

Sample Data:

```
timestamp
2020-05-01 08:00:00    132.05
2020-05-01 08:01:00    132.06
2020-05-01 08:02:00    132.06
2020-05-01 08:03:00    132.06
2020-05-01 08:04:00    132.06
```

Error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in between_time(self, start_time, end_time, include_start, include_end, axis)
   8123         try:
-> 8124             indexer = index.indexer_between_time(
   8125                 start_time,

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'indexer_between_time'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-8742423e2633> in <module>
      2 df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
      3 df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
----> 4 df.between_time('8:00', '12:00')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in between_time(self, start_time, end_time, include_start, include_end, axis)
   8129             )
   8130         except AttributeError:
-> 8131             raise TypeError("Index must be DatetimeIndex")
   8132 
   8133         return self.take(indexer, axis=axis)

TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: It would be impossible for us to reproduce this problem without sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Data Series - TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453164/pandas-data-series-typeerror-index-must-be-datetimeindex)

Comment: @Tibebes.M I dont think this answers it, I am new at python fyi. I'll inlcude the full Trace back

Answer (score 0):

The data was sampled and extracted for time periods. I have further added it to the average by day as an example. I have made my own judgement as there is no output etc. to expect. Does this fit the intent of your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2020-05-01',periods=100, freq='BH'),'value':np.random.randint(100,150,(100,))})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

df2 = df.iloc[df.index.indexer_between_time('08:00', '12:00')]

    value
timestamp   
2020-05-01 09:00:00 113
2020-05-01 10:00:00 113
2020-05-01 11:00:00 122
2020-05-01 12:00:00 116
2020-05-04 09:00:00 146
2020-05-04 10:00:00 129
2020-05-04 11:00:00 144
2020-05-04 12:00:00 123
2020-05-05 09:00:00 101
2020-05-05 10:00:00 140

df2.groupby(df2.index.day).agg(np.mean)

     value
timestamp   
1   116.00
4   135.50
5   126.25
6   123.50
7   115.50
8   124.25
11  111.00
12  133.75
13  131.00
14  127.00
15  127.00
18  115.00
19  132.75
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. Please accept the answer if it's not a problem.